# How can I get the max value of the sum value in a N x M matrix, each column and each rows can be chosen only once

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Example input:

```
3 4
10 20 30
40 10 30
20 10  0
 5 15  5
```

Example output:

```
1 3
2 1
4 2

85
```

30 + 40 + 15 = 85

I need get the result of a matrix with thousand rows and columns

Comment: Look for `assignment problem`

Comment: Since you are a new contributor, *you need to know that along with the question, you must mention what efforts have you made on your own*. What have you tried? What is not working correctly? Please add these details to your answer.